# ¿Algo parecido a un paso por referencia en flutter?

Tags: flutter

Tengo un widget personalizado para elegir fotos de la galería que recibe parámetros de la siguiente forma:

```
class AddPhotoButton extends StatefulWidget {

  late Uint8List image;
  late String imagePath;

   AddPhotoButton(
      {Key? key,
        required this.image,
        required this.imagePath,
        }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  AddPhotoButtonState createState() => AddPhotoButtonState();

}
```

Esto en dirección hacia delante funciona como pretendo, me explico:

1. Desde la  pantalla 1 hago click en el widget, y elijo una imagen.
2. Si en los argumentos que le paso hay algo guardado, la imagen se mostrará en el widget.

El problema viene cuando lo quiero hacer a la inversa, es decir, quiero que la imagen que selecciono en el Widget se pase al modelo. Tenía en mente que funcionaría de forma similar a C# con Blazor, donde todos los parámetros van automáticamente por referencia.

De manera que si yo llamo al widget de la siguiente forma:

```
 Padding(

                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
                          child: AddPhotoButton(image:model.image1, imagePath: model.image1path,),
                        ),
```

en model.image1 se debería quedar guardada la imagen.

Pero esto no ocurre, ya que la imagen se está guardando realmente dentro del Widget.

¿Existe alguna forma de lograr esto? He estado buscando y parece ser que Dart no acepta pasos por referencia de parámetros. Pero creo que tiene que haber alguna forma de conseguirlo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hace unos años escribí un artículo sobre comunicación entre widgets, lo dejo aquí: https://medium.com/comunidad-flutter/comunicaci%C3%B3n-entre-widgets-5f61b6c2e56c

Para tu caso, lo más sencillo podría ser usar Callbacks.

Tendrías que agregar este parámetro:

```dart
class AddPhotoButton extends StatefulWidget {

  final Uint8List image;
  final String imagePath;
  final ValueChanged<String> onImageSelected;

   AddPhotoButton(
      {Key? key,
        required this.image,
        required this.imagePath,
        required this.onImageSelected,
        }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  AddPhotoButtonState createState() => AddPhotoButtonState();

}
```

Al momento de que consigas la imagen o ruta dentro del widget `AddPhotoButton` , tendrías que hacer algo como esto:

```dart
widget.onImageSelected('la ruta de tu imagen');
```

Y la forma de capturar ese valor, sería así:

```dart
 Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30),
         child: AddPhotoButton(
                image:model.image1, 
                imagePath: model.image1path,
                onImageSelected: (tuImage) {   
                       print('Aquí tienes la ruta de tu imagen: $tuImage');
                     }
                             ),
                        ),
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, he podido solucionar el problema con tu metodo.